# What's a good resource to learn about advanced character and narrative development?

Tags: roleplaying, player-characters, narrative-balance

I've seen the "50 questions to ask yourself about your character" lists. Those are very helpful early on and I still use them after 10 years of roleplay.

I think I'd like to move into more advanced techniques. Things I can do as a player to wow other players. How to handle complicated situations like "I'm playing a god character who is extremely powerful, and I don't know how to entice them since they already have everything".

What would be a good resource for this?